# JSON response is not getting data when used NGROK's static domain

Tags: javascript, json, django, django-rest-framework, ngrok

I want to get JSON data so that it can be used in frontend.

```js
const authToken = 'e6f13bd9e9b74d540b8fc998b44e25bf2857cb5d';

        fetch('https://absolutely-relaxed-koala.ngrok-free.app/api/admin-products/', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Token ${authToken}`,
            },
        })
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
            }
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log('API Response:', data);

            if (Array.isArray(data)) {
                // Process the data as an array and add product items to the list
                const productList = document.getElementById('product-list');

                data.forEach(product => {
                    const listItem = document.createElement('tr');
                    listItem.textContent = `${product.name} - Price: $${product.product_image}`;

                    const image = document.createElement('img'); // Create an image element
                    image.src = product.product_image; // Set the image source to the product_image URL
                    listItem.appendChild(image); // Add the image to the list item
                    productList.appendChild(listItem);
                });
            } else {
                console.error('Invalid data structure. Expected an array.');
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error fetching products:', error);
        });
```

but I case of `'http://127.0.0.1:3000'` works fine with JSON response
while debugging a little I found out that the response is

```
 Response Data: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="author" content="ngrok">
    <meta name="description" content="ngrok is the fastest way to put anything on the internet with a single command.">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link id="style" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.ngrok.com/static/css/error.css">
    <noscript>You are about to visit absolutely-relaxed-koala.ngrok-free.app, served by 2402:e280:2238:1ec:84ed:7bb7:3e94:895e. This website is served for free through ngrok.com. You should only visit this website if you trust whoever sent the link to you. (ERR_NGROK_6024)</noscript>
    <script id="script" src="https://cdn.ngrok.com/static/js/error.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body id="ngrok">
    <div id="root" data-payload="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"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and in terminal

```
[19/Sep/2023 12:49:35] "OPTIONS /api/admin-products/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
[19/Sep/2023 12:49:35] "OPTIONS /api/admin-products/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
[19/Sep/2023 12:49:35] "OPTIONS /api/admin-products/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
```

Although I had configured `settings.py` as

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['absolutely-relaxed-koala.ngrok-free.app','127.0.0.1']
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
    'GET',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
    'PATCH',
    'DELETE',
    'OPTIONS',
]
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    'Authorization',  # Include any other headers your client needs to send
    'Content-Type',
]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "https://absolutely-relaxed-koala.ngrok-free.app",
    "http://localhost:63342",
]
```

and configured `INSTALLED_APPS` and `MIDDLEWARE` as well as the CORS policy.
I think the issue persists in 'OPTION' as redirection.
or there is some other issue.

Comment: Go to https://absolutely-relaxed-koala.ngrok-free.app/api/admin-products/ in your browser - it has instructions on how to handle this, below "To remove this page:"

Comment: I can't find any references in browser, is there any specific

Comment: Not sure what you are getting, I am seeing this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydT1p.png

Comment: oh okay, you are seeing this page because of ngrok only for security purpose, **"To remove this page"** is for security, I think that's not the issue here.
also domain works fine in Postman also but only case of integrating I doesn't get data in response

Comment: Yes, but not only _I_ am seeing it - _you_ are too. That response document you got up there in your question, that _is_ exactly the same source code as the page I am seeing (apart from the `data-payload` on the body element, that contains different IP addresses.) So your issue is the same here - your fetch request is currently getting blocked the same way, as I am getting blocked in my browser.

Comment: is used `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                "ngrok-skip-browser-warning": "69420",` in header, it says 'Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.'

Comment: Try sending a User-Agent instead then. (That is not a forbidden header name any more, so it does not need to be listed via `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name says there is a bug with this in Chrome though, not sure if that is still current.)

Answer (score 1):

PM from ngrok here. @CBroe is correct, you are seeing the abuse interstitial returned from ngrok. To fix the issue, add `ngrok-skip-browser-warning` to your fetch headers and set it to any value, which will skip this page and return your json payload.